# how to override bootstrap's container's padding

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a div with the container bootstrap class on it. So the container class gives a 15px padding on left and right sides. I want to keep the padding for all the children elements of my container but I want one div to stick to both of the sides of the container without complitely deleting the bootstrap padding. Is that possible ?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>first div</div>
  <div>second div div</div>
  <div>div that has to stick on the sides</div>
  <div>another random div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
.container{
 background-color: blue;
}

div{
   background-color: wheat;
}

#fullWidth{
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='fullWidth'>first div</div>
  <div>second div div</div>
  <div>div that has to stick on the sides</div>
  <div>another random div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The container class in Bootstrap has left and right padding of 15px for gutters. You can counteract that by using negative margins no the div you specified via:

```
div.container > div:nth-child(3){
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
```